# Non-SourceGraphic svg element as source for a filter?

Tags: svg

Can we create a filter such that it creates a temporary svg element and takes it as a source graphic?
Like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="700" height="700" >
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <rect id="rect1" width="30" height="30" fill="#aaaaaa"/>
            <feComposite in="url(#rect1)" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#ffffff" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <feImage>, like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="700" height="700" >
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feImage xlink:href="#rect1"/>
            <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over" />
        </filter>
        <rect id="rect1" width="30" height="30" fill="blue"/>
    </defs>

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="green" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2eRG/).

However, some browsers don't support <feImage> fully, e.g Firefox and IE, but it works fine in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! Exactly what I wanted!